# Definition of a groupoid of fractions

Tags: category-theory, definition, groupoids

The title sums it up : I am looking for a definition of "a groupoid of fractions for a category". I would be interested in any example someone might have as well...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if [this paper](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0004/0004133v1.pdf) by John Baez and James Dolan is what you want but there is a discussion of fractions starting on page 13. I am not competent to discuss it in any detail.